# Extracting coordinates with respect to the camera

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to extract real world coordinates of an object detected by the camera. I have the camera matrix and the distortion matrix. Since I have x, y(coordinates of object in image), I tried solving for (X,Y) to obtain coordinates of object with respect to camera. (Z = 0 since I know the plane on which the object is placed.)

[image]

However, there seems to be something wrong with this approach. Am I missing out something here?

Comment: you dont know w thats why you cant solve to X,Y,Z but only to a ray in 3d world and your point can be anywhere on that ray.

Comment: btw you can try to invert the camera matrix and multiply it from left to the equation which is very easy. after that if you enter x and y you have a X,Y,Z that only depend on the unknown w.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also have the distortion matrix and the rotation-translational matrix. Do I need to use them to obtain (X,Y) ?

Comment: yes. just invert the whole projection formula. but you will have w as unknown in the end.

Comment: How do I obtain the rotation-translation matrix?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that what you get is coordinates up to scale.  A large object far away will have the same image as a small object nearby.

You need to apply some external information about the object to be able to scale the coordinates.  It can either be some information about the object (e.g. its size), or using a stereo camera or other RGBD camera.

Comment: I know the size of the object but how do I scale it? Can you elaborate a bit more? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Wrong answer. The scale is known, since this is a calibrated setup.

Comment: The question didn't specify known scale.

Comment: Re-read the question: OP wrote "I have the camera matrix" and "Z = 0 since I know the plane on which the object is placed". Which of these you do not understand?

Comment: Question was edited.  When I read it, I don't recall seeing the Z=0

Answer (score 0):

You say that the Z world coordinate of the 3D point in question is known to be zero. I assume that your world coordinate frame is not the same as the camera coordinate frame, otherwise your point would be behind the sensor plane, and we're done. Therefore you must have (presumably as a result of a calibration procedure) a coordinate transform from the world frame to the camera one, represented as a 3x4 matrix Q = [R | t], so that world points on that plane project into the image as:

```
[x, y, w]' = K * Q * [X, Y, Z, 1]'
```

where "'" means transposition.

Denote with Qi the inverse coordinate transform from camera frame to world frame:

```
Qi = inv(Q) = [R' | (-R' * t)]
```

Using this matrix, we can write the camera center in world coordinates:

```
c_w = Qi * [0, 0, 0, 1]'
```

The pixel on the image plane which is the image of your world point has world coordinates:

```
i_w = Qi * Ki * [x, y, 1]'
```

where Ki = inv(K) is the inverse of the camera matrix.

All the points on the ray going from the camera center through that pixel have then world coordinates:

```
r_w = c_w + lambda * (i_w - c_w)
```

where lambda is a positive number.

You are looking for a particular point on such a ray, the one on the Z=0 plane. So, if you write this last equation in (X, Y, Z) components, and replace Z with 0, you get a linear system of 3 equations in the unknowns X, Y and lambda. Solve it and you get your answer.